# How to overcome a ValueError when working with multiple if conditions?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, valueerror

I'm trying to make a script that can identify if a folder name is a project or not. To do this I want to use multiple if conditions. But I struggle with the resulting ValueError that comes from checking, for example, the first letter of a folder name and if it is a Number. If it's a String i want to skip the folder and make it check the next one. Thank you all in advance for your help.
Cheers, Benn

I tried While and except ValueError: but haven't been successful with it.

**# Correct name to a project "YYMM_ProjectName" = "1908_Sample_Project"**

```
projectnames = ['190511_Waldfee', 'Mountain_Shooting_Test', '1806_Coffe_Prime_Now', '180410_Fotos', '191110', '1901_Rollercoaster_Vision_Ride', 'Musicvideo_LA', '1_Project_Win', '19_Wrong_Project', '1903_di_2', '1907_DL_2', '3401_CAR_Wagon']
```

**# Check conditions**

```
for projectname in projectnames:
    if int(str(projectname[0])) < 3 and int(projectname[1]) > 5 and ((int(projectname[2]) * 10) + int(projectname[3])) <= 12 and str(projectname[4]) == "_" and projectname[5].isupper():
        print('Real Project')
        print('%s is a real Project' % projectname)
        # print("Skipped Folders")
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E'

Comment: The issue is that you're converting the string (a number, or a letter) before it's confirmed to be a number or a letter. Thus, you should check if the string is a number or letter before you cast it into a integer. You can use [str.isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm).

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite to see what is going wrong.

Comment: You need to lookup exception treatment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from all the ifs...you may actually be better off using a [regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) match. You're parsing through each character, and expecting each individual one to be within a very limited character range.

I haven't tested this pattern string, so it may be incorrect or need to be tweaked for your needs.

```
import re

projectnames = ['1911_Waldfee', "1908_Project_Test", "1912_WinterProject", "1702_Stockfootage", "1805_Branded_Content"]

p = ''.join(["^", # Start of string being matched
             "[0-2]", # First character a number 0 through 2 (less than 3)
             "[6-9]", # Second character a number 6 through 9 (single digit greater than 5)
             "(0(?=[0-9])|1(?=[0-2]))", # (lookahead) A 0 followed only by any number 0 through 9 **OR** A 1 followed only by any number 0 through 2
             "((?<=0)[1-9]|(?<=1)[0-2])", # (lookbehind) Match 1-9 if the preceding character was a 0, match 0-2 if the preceding was a 1
             "_", # Next char is a "_"
             "[A-Z]", #Next char (only) is an upper A through Z
              ".*$" # Match anything until end of string 
    ])

for projectname in projectnames:
    if re.match(p, projectname):
        #print('Real Project')
        print('%s is a real Project' % projectname)
        # print("Skipped Folders")
```

**EDIT: ========================**

You can step-by-step test the pattern using the following...

```
projectname = "2612_UPPER"
p = "^[0-2].*$" # The first character is between 0 through 2, and anything else afterwards
if re.match(p, projectname): print(projectname) 
# If you get a print, the first character match is right.
# Now do the next
p = "^[0-2][6-9].*$" # The first character is between 0 through 2, the second between 6 and 9, and anything else afterwards
if re.match(p, projectname): print(projectname) 
# If you get a print, the first and second character match is right.
# continue with the third, fourth, etc.
```

Comment: Wow thank you for your fast answer, I get no more ValueErrors but it sadly didn't print anything.

Comment: That means the patter "p" isn't quite correct. In this case the `re.match(p, projectname)` will return the entire `projectname` on a complete match, or `None` if there is any issue with the match. I'll add a method for testing your regex step by step above.

Comment: Can you post a couple of examples of an actual `projectname` filename so we can test an actual match?

Comment: Sure I already provided one on top but here is the pattern. **YY = Year (XX18, XX19 (from 2019 for example) MM = Month (01 - 12) then an underscore "_" and the Projekt Name where the first letter is uppercase**. The rest of the name is random. So here are a few examples. 1908_Project_Test, 1912_WinterProject, 1702_Stockfootage, 1805_Branded_Content. Hope that helps.

Comment: OK. I updated the pattern again based on the filenames you gave me. They all work now. I would recommend going to that link and studying the regex tools. They are extremely valuable! :)

Comment: I'm going to take a look at regex tools in detail. You code was the only one I got to work. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is something that just gets the work done and may not be the most efficient way to do this.

Given your list of projects,

```
projectnames = [
    '190511_Waldfee', 
    'Mountain_Shooting_Test', 
    '1806_Coffe_Prime_Now', 
    '180410_Fotos', 
    '191110', 
    '1901_Rollercoaster_Vision_Ride', 
    'Musicvideo_LA', 
    '1_Project_Win', 
    '19_Wrong_Project', 
    '1903_di_2', 
    '1907_DL_2', 
    '3401_CAR_Wagon'
    ]
```

I see that there are a limited number of valid YYMM strings (24 of them to be more precise). So I first create a list of these 24 valid YYMMs.

```
nineteen = list(range(1900, 1913))
eighteen = list(range(1800, 1813))
YYMM = nineteen + eighteen    # A list of all 24 valid dates
```

Then I modify your for loop a little bit using a try-except-else block,

```
for projectname in projectnames:

    try:
        first_4_digits = int(projectname[:4])  # Make sure the first 4 are digits.
    except ValueError:
        pass  # Pass silently
    else:
        if (first_4_digits in YYMM
            and projectname[4] == "_"
            and projectname[5].isupper()):
            # if all conditions are true
            print("%s is a real project." % projectname)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to make a quick function that catches an error and returns false:

```
def isInt(elem):
    try:
        int(elem)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
...

if all(isInt(e) for e in projectname[:3]) and int(str(projectname[0])) < 3 and ...:
    ...
```

Or you could use something like `str.isdigit()` as a check first, rather than writing your own function, to avoid triggering the ValueError in the first place.

---

Though if I were you I would reconsider why you need such a long and verbose `if` statement in the first place. There might be a more efficient way to implement this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your creative and well-approached answer. I replaced all int() functions with str.isdigit() and get no more ValueError problems but it doesn't print anything sadly. And I don't know why?

Comment: Also I'm a beginner if there is a smarter way to check through the first 5 letters/numbers I'm open to hear a suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small parser (might be a bit over the top, admittedly):

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor
from parsimonious.exceptions import ParseError

projectnames = ['190511_Waldfee', 'Mountain_Shooting_Test', '1806_Coffe_Prime_Now', '180410_Fotos', '191110', '1901_Rollercoaster_Vision_Ride', 'Musicvideo_LA', '1_Project_Win', '19_Wrong_Project', '1903_di_2', '1907_DL_2', '3401_CAR_Wagon']

class ProjectVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    grammar = Grammar(
        r"""
        expr    = first second third fourth fifth rest
        first   = ~"[0-2]"
        second  = ~"[6-9]"
        third   = ~"\d{2}"
        fourth  = "_"
        fifth   = ~"[A-Z]"
        rest    = ~".*"
        """
    )

    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_third(self, node, visited_children):
        x, y = int(node.text[0]), int(node.text[1])
        if not (x * 10 + y) <= 12:
            raise ParseError

# loop over them
pv = ProjectVisitor()
for projectname in projectnames:
    try:
        pv.parse(projectname)
        print("Valid project name: {}".format(projectname))
    except ParseError:
        pass
```

This yields

```
Valid project name: 1806_Coffe_Prime_Now
Valid project name: 1901_Rollercoaster_Vision_Ride
Valid project name: 1907_DL_2
```